# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation Always gets null

Tags: android

I'm trying to mark current user location in a maps activity but the call of LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation always returns null

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        Toast.makeText(this,"Client Connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        LatLng myLocation = null;
        if(mLastLocation!=null) {
            myLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                    mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation,
                    mMap.getMaxZoomLevel() - 5));
        }
    } else {
        // Show rationale and request permission.
    }


}
 }
```

Also i have added the permission in manifest file

when checking for mGoogleApiClient for connectivity it's always not connected

Comment: Do not attempt to call `getLastLocation()` until `onConnected()` is called, not sooner.

Comment: It's working not but it's not accurate at all, any recommendations ?

Comment: Well, you appear to only have coarse location permission. It's supposed to be inaccurate. Also, `getLastKnownLocation()` does not specify anything in terms of quality, and so it may be specifically using low-power approaches.

Comment: So what's else can i use ? FINELocation permission ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a listener to the location events, and start listening for a short period of time to several locations received, and compare their accuracy , source, etc, to determine which is the best one, and use that one.

Read [Location strategies](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) google documentation, which is pretty useful and has code examples of what you need to do to get accurate locations.

Also add this permission to the manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`